# Usar una cadena de texto para llamar a una propiedad en C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Si tengo un contexto de Entity Framework el cual lo inyecto en un controller de esta manera:

```
app.MapGet("/", (MiContext db) =>
{
    var query = from x in db.MiTabla
                select .....etc
});
```

¿Cómo puedo reemplazar MiTabla con un string de esta forma?:

```
app.MapGet("/", (MiContext db) =>
{
    string tabla = "MiTabla";

    var query = from x in db.tabla //no funciona
                select .....etc

    var query = from x in db[tabla] //no funciona
                select .....etc
});
```

C# no es Javascript...

Comment: no de esta forma.. probaste con linq comun?

Comment: Que seria linq comun, no tengo mucha idea de c#, soy mas del lado de js

Comment: No creo que se pueda porque necesitas el tipo de dato  (Type) de la tabla, ahora si el string que tu pasas fuera el tipo de dato (en vez del nombre), me parece que se puede hacer. Lo otro es usar una sentencia de SQL de toda la vida

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿Cuál es el objetivo de hacer eso?

Comment: @fredyfx si tienes 50 tablas que se llaman user-argentina, users-uruguay, users-chile y asi con 50 paises tengo que hacer un switch con 50 opciones. En vez de eso mando desde el front un parametro en el req con el nombre de la tabla y lo reemplazo en dbcontext.tabla. en js, q es mi lenguaje d trabajo lo hago asi. Estoy con c# tocando de oido y queria simplificar las cosas.

Comment: Pues, si vas a querer simplificar las cosas, sí o sí vas a tener que estudiar y practicar más, aquí está el escenario que tienes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64950626/3613462 Ten en cuenta que es Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Otra opción sería que llames a un Store Procedure y como la estructura de todas las tablas parece que son las mismas, una sola clase con dichas propiedades y fin del tema, la complejidad recae en el SP y para ello, esto te será de ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234005/3613462 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

**Entity Framework** te permite ejecutar **consultas SQL** puras:

```
var listaPersonas = db.Database.SqlQuery<Persona>("Select * from Personas");
```

Utilizando la **clase Database** del contexto de datos y el **método SqlQuery** puedes ejecutar cualquier **consulta SQL** desde **Linq**.

En tu caso específico podrías usar algo como esto:

```
string tabla = "MiTabla";
var listaPersonas = db.Database.SqlQuery<Persona>(string.Format("Select * from {0}", tabla));
```

Aquí utilizas el **método Format** para darle formato a tu consulta insertando el valor de la **variable tabla** en el lugar especificado de tu cadena de texto.

```
<Persona>
```

Indica el tipo de datos que va a devolver tu consulta, en este caso devolverá una lista de personas, pero si por ejemplo quisieras devolver los nombres podráas hacer lo siguiente:

```
var listaNombres = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(string.Format("Select Nombre from {0}", tabla));
```

También puedes especificar un tipo de datos creado por ti:

```
var lista = db.Database.SqlQuery<MiClase>(string.Format("Select Nombre, Edad from {0}", tabla));
```

Aqui estas devolviendo un tipo de datos creado por ti que tiene dos propiedades, un **string** para el nombre y un **int** para la edad.

Por tanto tu tipo de datos bien podría verse de esta forma:

```
public class MiClase
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Edad{ get; set; }
}
```

A esto último también se le conoce como el **patrón DTO**, puedes buscar mas información en Internet si lo deseas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero la idea seria no usar sql puro, por el tema del sql inyection. De hecho me piden q lo haga con linq exclusivamente

Comment: Si lo que quieres es aumentarle la seguridad, lecturas recomendadas: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations?redirectedfrom=MSDN + https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb896238(v=vs.100)

Comment: Aqui lo estas haciendo en Linq, no hay peligro de inyeccion de sql